# Transforming a string to an integer

Tags: java, math, input

What i am striving to achieve: Given a simple equation, you should output the correct value for variable "x". The equation has two numbers greater than 0 and variable "x", and between these can be "+", "-" or "=". Numbers, variable "x", symbols "+", "-", "=" all separated by a space.

the problem: when i read the numbers they come out as strings instead of integers

I am very new to codeing and tried this but i don't get why when i use var and input a number it reads it as a string instead of an integer

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int outpt;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    var sig1 = scanner.next();
    var sig2 = scanner.next();
    var sig3 = scanner.next();
    var sig4 = scanner.next();
    var sig5 = scanner.next();

    if(sig2 == "=")
    {
        if(sig1 == (int)sig1)
        {
            if(sig3 == (int)sig3)
            {
                if(sig4 == "-")
                {
                    outpt = sig3 - sig1;
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println(outpt);
                }
                else
                {
                    outpt = sig1 - sig3;
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println(outpt);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(sig4 == "-")
                {
                    outpt = sig5 + sig1;
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println(outpt);
                }
                else
                {
                    outpt = sig1 - sig5;
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println(outpt);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(sig4 == "-")
                {
                    outpt = sig3 - sig5;
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println(outpt);
                }
                else
                {
                    outpt = sig3 + sig5;
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println(outpt);
                }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(sig5 == (int)sig5)
        {
            if(sig1 == (int)sig1)
            {
                if(sig2 == "+")
                {
                    outpt = sig5 - sig1;
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println(outpt);
                }
                else
                {
                    outpt = sig1 - sig5;
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println(outpt);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(sig2 == "+")
                {
                    outpt = sig5 - sig3;
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println(outpt);
                }
                else
                {
                    outpt = sig3 + sig5;
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println(outpt);

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(sig2 == "+")
            {
                outpt = sig1 + sig3;
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println(outpt);
            }
            else
            {
                outpt = sig1 - sig3;
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println(outpt);
            }
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Sample Input 1:

5 + x = 15
Sample Output 1:

10

Sample Input 2:

x - 8 = 10
Sample Output 2:

18

Sample Input 3:

x = 20 - 15
Sample Output 3:

5

Comment: Hi. To read number as int you need `nextInt()` or convert them after reading by using `Integer.parseInt()` Moreover please don't compare strings using `==`. For that use `str1.equals(str2)`

Comment: but what if i don't know if the value i'm gonna read is an int or not?

Comment: Create a method `boolean isInt(String)` where you check it and see if it throws an error. If it does return `false` otherwise `true`. Also you can separate out numbers, symbols and alphabets using regex.

Comment: this helps a lot, thx

Comment: i will post the solution once i have it

Comment: Please don't do it like [this](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/a-loop-in-the-string)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 100 if statements try this. In my code I am taking whole equation as input and storing it in array and then saving the position of symbols and numbers in variables which I can later use the decide what operation I should perform

Here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AlgebraEquation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the whole equation: ");
        String equation = scan.nextLine();
        scan.close();

        String[] equationSplit = equation.split(" ");

        // This code block is just to show how logic is working
        for (int i = 0; i < equationSplit.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(equationSplit[i] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        int xPosition = -1, const1Pos = -1, const2Pos = -1, equalPos = -1, operatorPos = -1;

        // Checking each index of array and saving position of characters
        for (int i = 0; i < equationSplit.length; i++) {
            if (equationSplit[i].equalsIgnoreCase("X")) {
                xPosition = i;
            } else if (equationSplit[i].equals("=")) {
                equalPos = i;
            } else if (equationSplit[i].matches("[-+*/]")) { // If character matches any of these "-+*/"
                operatorPos = i;
            } else {
                // Checking if const1Pos is filled or not
                if (const1Pos < 0) {
                    const1Pos = i;
                } else {
                    const2Pos = i;
                }
            }
        }

        // This code block is just to show how logic is working
        System.out.println(equationSplit[xPosition] + " Position: " + xPosition);
        System.out.println(equationSplit[equalPos] + " Position: " + equalPos);
        System.out.println(equationSplit[operatorPos] + " Position: " + operatorPos);
        System.out.println(equationSplit[const1Pos] + " Position: " + const1Pos);
        System.out.println(equationSplit[const2Pos] + " Position: " + const2Pos);

        String operator = equationSplit[operatorPos];
        switch (operator) {
        case "+":
            System.out.println("Addition");
            // Do you calculation based on relative position of equal, const1Pos, and
            // const2Pos
            break;
        case "-":
            System.out.println("Subtraction");
            break;
        case "*":
            System.out.println("Multiplication");
            break;
        case "/":
            System.out.println("Division");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

> Output

```
Enter the whole equation: 5 + x = 8 //(Enter Key Pressed)
5, +, x, =, 8, 
x Position: 2
= Position: 3
+ Position: 1
5 Position: 0
8 Position: 4
Addition
```

Answer (score -1):

this is the final code it came to

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String a = scanner.next();
        String b = scanner.next();
        String c = scanner.next();
        String d = scanner.next();
        String e = scanner.next();

        if (b.equals("+") && a.equals("x")) {
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(e) - Integer.parseInt(c));
        } else if (b.equals("+") && c.equals("x")) {
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(e) - Integer.parseInt(a));
        } else if (b.equals("-") && a.equals("x")) {
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(e) + Integer.parseInt(c));
        } else if (b.equals("-") && c.equals("x")) {
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(a) - Integer.parseInt(e));
        } else if (d.equals("+") && c.equals("x")) {
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(a) - Integer.parseInt(e));
        } else if (d.equals("+") && e.equals("x")) {
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(a) - Integer.parseInt(c));
        } else if (d.equals("-") && c.equals("x")) {
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(a) + Integer.parseInt(e));
        } else if (d.equals("-") && e.equals("x")) {
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(c) - Integer.parseInt(a));
        } else if (b.equals("+") && e.equals("x")) {
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(c) + Integer.parseInt(a));
        } else if (d.equals("+") && a.equals("x")) {
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(c) + Integer.parseInt(e));
        } else if (b.equals("-") && e.equals("x")) {
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(a) - Integer.parseInt(c));
        } else if (d.equals("-") && a.equals("x")) {
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(c) - Integer.parseInt(e));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is an answer for the problem and not the specific question itself.

Comment: I would suggest that store the whole input line in a string using `nextLine();` and split it array using `array.split(" ");` Then use for loop to get positions of X, = and numbers.